# Tcpdump logfile

Tags: linux, tcpdump

the thing is I am trying transfer log file from one server to another dividing by size. I have dump such as:

```
tcpdump -i any tcp x.x.x.x -s 0 -G 86400 -w /var/log/%F.zip
```

Questions are:

1. The output file released every 24 hours will be huge and I don't know how to split by size 50Mb every like that for example:

   ```
   2019-10-10-1.zip / 2019-10-10-2.zip/2019-10-10-3.zip
   ```

   then

   ```
   2019-10-11-1.zip / 2019-10-11-2.zip/2019-10-11-3.zip
   ```
2. in the code above I store logfile in this server where I run tcpdump but I would like to store on another server. Ofc adresses private:) Servers on Linux(centos).

Answer (score 0):

You can split the file by any size, no need to make it daily.

Run `tcpdump -r <input_pcap> -w <output_pcap> -C <file_size>`, where input_pcap is the name of the fie you want to split, output_pcap is the output, and  is the approximate size of the split files in megabytes.

Example: tcpdump -r input_packet_capture.pcap -w output_packet_capture -C 50 will split the file into 50MB chunks.

The second part is a little unclear. You could make for example a cron schedule to move the already split files to another server if you need that.